# Show what foreign key is referring to

Tags: mysql

```
                   **Student Table**
            ---------------------------------
            id    name  address placeofbirth
            ---------------------------------
            1     Kim     1          2
            2     ahmed   3          4
            3     john    1          3

                **City Table**
            ---------------------------------
                id    name
            ---------------------------------
                1     New York
                2     Boston
                3     Denver
                4     Washington


                **Result**
            -----------------------------------------
            Student        address      Placeofbirth
            -----------------------------------------
            Kim            New York        Boston
            ahmed          Denver          Washington
            John           New York        Denver
```

I don't have a bridging table to connect them, please help me on how can I achieve the desired result, I am using mysql and c#

Comment: you have place of birth  .. that match with city id .. this is the relation for the result and adresss tio

Comment: Yes both address and the place of birth if foreign key and referring to city table, please help me i'm new to programming. Can you show me the code in mysql?

Comment: i have posted  an answer  hope is clear ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.name as Student, a.name AS address, p.name AS Placeofbirth 
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN City a ON s.address = a.id
INNER JOIN City p ON s.placeofbirth = p.id;
```

Read more on JOINs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Answer (score 2):

you have place of birth .. that match with city id .. this is the relation for the result and adresss too  this is another relation

so you can simply join for both the column related  to you city table

```
select s.student, a.name address, b.name Placeofbirth
from Student s 
inner join City a on a.id = s.address 
inner join City b on b.id = s.Placeofbirth
```

twice fk.. twice join